# Delete function of a binary search tree does not delete leaf node

Tags: go, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a binary search tree in Go.
So far, I managed to implement the following functions:

- search
- insert
- in order traversal

The only function I didn't manage to implement successfully yet is the delete function.
When the node to be deleted is a leaf, it does not get deleted.

When I try to delete the node containing the value 8, I am expecting the following output:

```
{10 <nil> 0xc00009a060}
{12 <nil> <nil>}
{15 0xc00009a018 0xc00009a030}
{18 <nil> <nil>}
{20 0xc00009a078 0xc00009a090}
{25 <nil> <nil>}
```

However, I get the following output:

```
{8 <nil> <nil>}
{10 0xc00009a048 0xc00009a060}
{12 <nil> <nil>}
{15 0xc00009a018 0xc00009a030}
{18 <nil> <nil>}
{20 0xc00009a078 0xc00009a090}
{25 <nil> <nil>}
```

You can find my source code here: https://play.golang.org/p/oaCYEgCt-qI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
if value < tree.data {
    *parent = *tree
    tree = tree.left
} else if value > tree.data {
    *parent = *tree
    tree = tree.right
}
```

In this section `*parent = *tree` is taking a copy of the node. Later on you use `parent.right = nil` which amends the copy (not the node that is linked from above in the tree). So changing `*parent = *tree` to `parent = tree` resolves the issue ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ga8xoJWfM1A)). Note that you also need to consider what should happen if the found node is the top of the tree (I have not addressed that case).